# dual boot/ grub menu option issue

Tags: linux, windows-8, boot, grub, ubuntu-14.04

I did not know about the partition thing to do first in windows in command line, and start installing linux ubuntu by bootable flash drive. Now, whenever I open my laptop( dell i7), it doesnot show any grub menu and start ubuntu. how do I recover my windows as my whole data is in there. please help! I'm using linux ubuntu 14.04 and windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn´t specify any partition for the install, your Windows disk has probably been overwrite with Ubuntu. Even if you reinstall Windows with an install disk you will not recover your partition. And actually, the more you move files and the less you´re likely to find back your data.

In this use case your best change is using a 3rd party recovery software which will look for missing data. Here you have a complete channel which explain how to use testdisk.

[How to use testdisk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu)

I hope you will be able to recover some missing data.